# How to fetch the instance ID of which each EC2 Health event belongs to using Boto 3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am currently able to list down all the health events(EC2) of all regions using 'describe_events'  function via Boto 3 SDK. But it does not return the instance ID of which that each event belongs to.  Is there a way to get the instance ID of each event via Boto 3 SDK? Thanks.